Closed form of binomial summation using complex numbers

Calculate the sum: $1 + {n \choose 1}\cos \theta + {n \choose 2}\cos 2\theta + \cdots+ {n \choose n}\cos n\theta$


I found a solution here:

The given sum is the real part of
$$\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}e^{ik\theta}=(1+e^{i\theta})^n=e^{in\theta/2}\left(2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\right)^n$$
so the desired sum is
$$2^n\cos^{n}\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\cos\left(\frac{n\theta}2\right)$$


I did not understand the second equality, how they got $\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}e^{ik\theta}=(1+e^{i\theta})^n=e^{in\theta/2}\left(2\cos\left(\frac{\theta}2\right)\right)^n$, I can't seem to get how these two are equal, can anyone please help. Thanks!

There are 2 equality signs there. Are you confused by both, or do you understand the first one?

@CalvinLin oh my bad I forgot to mention, I understand the first equality, it's the second equality

The equality $\displaystyle\sum_{k=0}^n{n\choose k}e^{ik\theta}=(1+e^{i\theta})^n$ is the standard Newton's binomial formula.
For the second, $$(1+e^{i\theta})^n=e^{in\theta/2}\left(e^{-i\theta/2}+e^{i\theta/2}\right)^n=e^{in\theta/2}\left(2\cos(\theta/2)\right)^n$$
Because $\cos(z)=\dfrac{e^{iz}+e^{-iz}}{2}$ for every $z\in\mathbb{C}$.

The first equality follows from the Binomial theorem. For any natural number $n$, $$(1+z)^n = \sum_{k=0}^{n}\binom{n}{k}z^k,$$
now simply put $z = e^{i\theta} = \cos{\theta}+i\sin{\theta}$. For the second equality, use $1+\cos{\theta} = 2\cos^2{\theta/2}$ and $\sin{\theta} = 2\sin{(\theta/2)}\cos{(\theta/2)}$, this will imply $$ 1+e^{i\theta} = 2\cos{\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}\left(\cos{\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)+i\sin{\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}}\right) = 2\cos{\left(\frac{\theta}{2}\right)}e^{i\frac{\theta}{2}}.$$
